# why is the 3D model not rendering on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, three.js, frontend

I used chatgpt to generate the code for three js
I also did 'npm install three'
still the 3D model is not rendering

[image: my code 1]

[image: my code 2]

i want my 3d model to render on my page.js , located in the app folder directly
i think the code inside ModelViewer.js

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader';
```

is somehow wrong because when I write three/, it shows me src, build and examples folders, there is no such thing as addons
when I am writing import { GLTFLoader } from 'three', it is telling me (loader is not a constructor)(line 27 in ModelViewer.js)

what do I do?

Comment: I am guessing ChatGPT is referring to the [three-addons package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-addons). You should not expect ChatGPT to write code that is going to just work. Also, ChatGPT cutoff date is Sep 2021, so it would not take into account any changes made to three.js after that date.